# Hibernate method name to SQL query - OR statement

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My entity has 2 dates - startingDate, buildingDate.

I need a query that finds all rows with either date between 2 parameter dates.

```
public List<Factory> findByStartingDateBetweenOrBuildingDateBetween(LocalDate from, Localdate to);
```

Writing such method gives me an error and I have to extend parameters by another 2 dates.

```
public List<Factory> findByStartingDateBetweenOrBuildingDateBetween(LocalDate from, Localdate to, LocalDate fromDate, LocalDate toDate);
```

Is there a way to write such method that only takes 2 parameters and assigns them to both dates in the query?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do what you want, and your second version is semantically correct, and is the version I would want in my own codebase anyway.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE start_date >=:from AND start_date<=:to
by using this query you can get the list of data in between this date

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below method will works for you.

```
public List<Factory> findAllByStartingDateLessThanEqualAndBuildingDateGreaterThanEqual(LocalDate startingDate, LocalDate buildingDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below native query above the method, Hope this will works for you.

select * from factory where (starting_date>=:from and starting_date<=:to) or (building_date>=:from and building_date<=:to);

Answer (score 0):

try this-

1. native query method -

```
@Query(value = "select * from factory where (starting_date>= ?1 AND starting_date<= ?2) OR (building_date>= ?1 and building_date<= ?2)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Factory> findFactoryByDate(LocalDate from, Localdate to);
```

2. JPA QUERY METHOD

```
public List<Factory> findByStartingDateOrBuildingDateBetween(LocalDate from, Localdate to);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Factory> findAllByStartingDateBetween(Date Start, Date End);
```